# Swagger does not consider, that body is not required

Tags: http-post, swagger, required-field

I define endpoints with Swagger file, and for one of the endpoints the body (a JSON) is not required.
I describe it in this way in the yaml file:

```
      - in: "body"
        name: "body"
        description: "some description here..."
        required: false
        schema:
          type: string
```

After that I generate code from the Swagger file and for the body I get the following description in the method for this endpoint in the generated class:

```
@Valid @RequestBody String body
```

the generated file is an interface, and when I implement the method, and call the endpoint without setting a body, I get:

```
Resolved [org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException: Required request body is missing:
```

Can somebody tell me what I am doing wrong? When I put

```
@RequestBody(required=false) String body
```

, then everything works correct, but I would like this (required=false) to be generated automatically from the code generator...

Comment: What code generator do you use? E.g. Swagger Codegen, openapi-generator? And what version?

Comment: The code generation is part of the maven build so:

openapi-generator-maven-plugin

is used, and its version is 

3.3.4

and actually the things were copied from here:
https://www.north-47.com/knowledge-base/generate-spring-boot-rest-api-using-swagger-openapi/

Comment: Looks like this issue: https://github.com/OpenAPITools/openapi-generator/issues/2062, https://github.com/OpenAPITools/openapi-generator/issues/3134